# Elegant way of copying an ArrayList into two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am basically reading a text file into a List and I am copying the contents of the `ArrayList` into `Object[][]` like below. I need the to keep the return format `Object[][]` to use it in some other function. Is there any elegant way of doing this in Java? Thanks in advance.

```
public Object[][] getResults() {
  List<String> arrList =FileUtils.readLines(new File("myfile.txt"));   
  Object[][] result=new Object[arrList.size()][];       
  //how do I optimize this code below?
  int i=0;
  for(String s:arrList){
     result[i]=new Object[]{new String(s)};
     i++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: How does a list translate into a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: Change `{new String(s)}` to {s}.  You already have a perfectly usable string, so creating a brand new one in this fashion is pointless.  Other than that, the creation runs in linear time - I'm not completely sure that there *is* anything better (save changing the return type, which might still result in a linear time operation anyways).

Comment: Kal- The column dimension in this code is almost useless. I am creating Object[10][] (lets assume 10 is list size)

Comment: X-zero..You are right..I fixed it to {new String(s)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new String instance. Strings are immutable, and it's perfectly OK to share and reuse them.

```
int i = 0;
for (String s : arrList) {
    result[i] = new Object[] {s};
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the String instance. Would there be any alternative so that I could avoid this for loop. I may have to go through thousands of records and I am trying to reduce performance bottlenecks

Comment: No. A loop is necessary. But before trying to optimize, have you measured and identified a performance problem with this code?

Comment: I haven't measured the performance of this yet, thought in general it would have performed better without a for loop if there was an alternative way